# Error in build while installing RTAI in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, deb, make, linux-headers, realtime

I am trying to install RTAI 5.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Linux Kernel 4.1.18. I was following [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/thefreakengineer/tutorials/rtai-5-0-1-lubuntu-16-04-x64-2).
But unfortunately I am stuck in this part

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-rtai
```

The error is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'deb-pkg'.  Stop.
```

What should be the target?

Answer (score 1):

Found out I was in the wrong folder. [Solved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475671/error-in-build-while-installing-rtai-in-ubuntu-18-04).